# back button error, action down

Tags: android, android-button

I have a problem with my code about back button. I've tried a lot of answers here in this site.
I have the mainActivity that calls a second activity with startActivityforResult. This second activity starts bluetooth and show a list of the bonded devices, but if I press the backbutton it stops the app with an error.

```
public class Main extends Activity implements OnSeekBarChangeListener{
...

@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        String address = data.getExtras().getString(BondedDevices.DEVICE_ADDRESS);
        if (resultCode==Activity.RESULT_CANCELED){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Finalizando dispositivos pareados", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
        switch (requestCode) {
        case DISPOSITIVOS_PAREADOS:
            if(resultCode==Activity.RESULT_OK){
                mConnectThread = new ConnectThread(address);
                mConnectThread.start();
                estado = EST_CONECTADO;   //informa que esta conectado
                atualizaEstado();
                break;
            } 
        return;
        }
    }
```

But when I am in the second activity, and try to back to the mainactivity just pressing the back button, I get an error on main activity and my app return an error:

```
public class BondedDevices extends ListActivity {
....

@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(D) Log.e(TAG, "+++ ON BACK PRESSED +++");
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED);
        this.finish();
    }
```

or like this:

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
        {
            switch(keyCode)
            {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
                setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED, returnIntent);
                finish();
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false; 
    }
```

I have tried a lot of different code, but it still doesn't work. Please someone help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

you should call `super.onBackPressed();`

like this

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    if(D) Log.e(TAG, "+++ ON BACK PRESSED +++");
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED);
    this.finish();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you return from the second `Activity`, you have not set an `Intent` as the data for the result in the back button case, yet the first thing you do before checking the value of `resultCode` for `RESULT_CANCELED` is try to obtain the address from the `Intent`, which is null so this will cause a `NullPointerException`.

You need to reorder the lines in your `onActivityResult()` to look more like this:

```
if (resultCode==Activity.RESULT_CANCELED){
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Finalizando dispositivos pareados", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return;
}
//Do this after checking for cancel
String address = data.getExtras().getString(BondedDevices.DEVICE_ADDRESS);

/* The rest of the existing code */
```

Also, you should NOT override BOTH the `onBackPressed()` and `onKeyDown()`, stick with one of them.  You're only causing confusion about which code path gets called first.  Even in the case where the result is set with a blank `Intent`, you will still get a `NullPointerException` in your existing code because the extras bundle of that `Intent` will still be null.